# How to count the frequency of numbers that meet certain criteria e.g. ISODD and > 50 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

What is the Excel formula to count the frequency of numbers occurring in a list against some criteria. E.g. how many odd numbers are in the list, how many even numbers are there with values > 50 or how many odd numbers with values < 50 etc.?

Comment: Come again? What is the use case? What are you trying to achieve? Your question does not make any sense, because as posed, exactly half of each group is even and the other half in uneven. Because in any sequence every other number is even.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised Solution**

```
    =SUM(ISODD(A2:A101+0) * (A2:A101 > 50))
```

This is an array formula, so finalise the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and not just enter.

**Explanation**

There were quite a few issues with writing this formula and would explain why you struggled. My first attempt were:

```
=SUMIF(AND(ISODD(A2:A101),(A2:A101) > 50),"= TRUE")
```

The problems here are SUMIF only works on ranges directly, AND doesn't work on arrays and ISODD doesn't work on arrays unless you trick it. Normally I would just give up on the single cell/single formula idea and create a few columns and do this cell by cell e.g. B2 = AND(ISODD(A2),A2 > 50)+0 then SUM that column.

Lets fix it. First replace SUMIF with just a boolean to number converted SUM:

```
=SUM(AND(ISODD(A2:A101),(A2:A101) > 50)+0)
```

To make AND array capable we will replace it with a standard multiply operator (with the * in there we can drop the +0)

```
=SUM(ISODD(A2:A101) * (A2:A101 > 50))
```

Lastly we need to fix ISODD to be array capable with (ODD(A2:A101) = A2:A101) or the recently learned trick ISODD(A2:A101+0), which tricks ISODD to deal with arrays

```
=SUM(ISODD(A2:A101+0) * (A2:A101 > 50))                       ------> CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER!
```

For additional criteria e.g.

```
=SUM(ISODD(A2:A101+0) * (A2:A101 > 50) * (A2:A101 <= 100))    ------> CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER!
```

Comment: Solves my problem Thanks

Comment: Hi @Gaby, do check mark the solution! I'll edit my post to highlight some of the issues with this formula. It is not trivial!